# How do I remove myself from an Event on Facebook when the "Attendees" are not displayed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

Facebook have removed the option to remove an Event whilst on the same page as the actual Invite.

I did find the new information for removing an Event by going to the Event

- `Declining` and then going to the `Attendees` list displayed on the left side
- clicking `Invited`
- Once the box opens, clicking the drop arrow and selecting `Declined`
- You can then click the `X` which removes you.

However, now I am getting Events where people aren't displaying the Attendee information on their Events. Which means I can no longer remove myself.

Even if you `Block` an individual, the Event does not disappear. If it's a `Page` that is sending the invite you can't block them. I have tried `unliking` the page and that does nothing either.

I get lots of invites to events, which I use for reference, but I only want to see the events that I am going to attend or have attended.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a way to remove an event. You have first to join or decline, then you click on the "going" list or "Maybe" list. You'll find yourself & a small "x" next to it.
Click "x" to remove the event.

Answer (score 1):

As of today I noticed you can do it this way:

1. go to event page
2. left side bar under the Invited list
3. blue text link options: Export · Share · Report · Remove
4. Click Remove

This allows you to do the same thing as before in the event pop up, which is remove the even from your list of events without having to actually respond with a decline. I believe this should also unsubscribe you from any further updates.

Comment: To the person who answered "As of today I noticed you can do it this way":
Sorry but on the Event page there are only 3 options under "invited" - Export, Share and Report. The way to remove yourself is as described in the reply that starts "I did find the new information for removing an Event by going to the Event". THIS WORKS (only if you've declined, of course).

Comment: (@AlisonMoodie: The part that starts with "_"I did find the new information for removing an Event by going to the Event_" is not in a _reply_, but in (an edited version of) the question.)